# How can I take a variadic std::tuple as a template argument?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a struct

```
template <typename Args>
struct MyStruct
{
};
```

But I only want to be able to instantiate this class with `std::tuple` instantiations, e.g.

```
Mystruct<std::tuple<>> a; // OK
Mystruct<std::tuple<int, int, double>> a; // OK
Mystruct<double> a; // FAIL
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple. Declare but not define a general template:

```
template<typename T> struct Mystruct;
```

then define a specialization:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct Mystruct<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
// stuff
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to krzaq's answer, to have a better error message, you might want to use `static_assert`

```
// The traits:
template <typename T>
struct is_a_tuple : std::false_type {};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct is_a_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

// Your structure (for error message)
template <typename T>
struct MyStruct
{
    static_assert(is_a_tuple<T>::value, "T should be a std::tuple");
};

// Your structure (for std::tuple)
template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyStruct<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    // Your implementation
};
```